# No module named 'pip'

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, pip

In one of my projects, PIP3 suddenly stopped working. I tried reinstalling it using the appropriate commands :

```
sudo apt-get remove python3-pip
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

But that didn't change anything.

```
pip3 -V  

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/roman/firtsdjango/myvenv/bin/pip3", line 7, in <module>
    from pip import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'



python3 -m pip3 -V
/home/roman/firtsdjango/myvenv/bin/python3: No module named pip3

python3 -m pip -V 
/home/roman/firtsdjango/myvenv/bin/python3: No module named pip
```

Comment: POP3 or pip3? They're very different things.

Comment: @Roman What happens when you run `myenv/bin/python -m pip -V` ?

Comment: @Roman not `pip3`, just `pip`. `myenv/bin/python -m pip -V`

Comment: After the reinstall, could you try to create a new `virtualenv` again ? I am guessing, the virtualenv you are using is created before you reinstalled the python3-pip ? And after removing, the links maybe broken, so you may need to create a fresh one again

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pip for python2 while python3 pip exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62771974/pip-for-python2-while-python3-pip-exists)