# Pip for python2 while python3 pip exists

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I have both `python2` and `python3` in my system. But when I try :

```
python -m pip install sklearn
```

`bash` shows :

> /usr/bin/python: No module named pip

And

```
pip --version
```

Yields :

> pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)

Python versions are `Python 2.7.18` and `Python 3.8.2`.
**How to correct this error by having two pip versions?**

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11268501/how-to-use-pip-with-python-3-x-alongside-python-2-x) is a similar question, but did not solve the issue.

OS is Ubuntu.

Comment: `pip` default version is Python 3. You can use `pip2` for using pip of Python 2.x.

Hope that this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11272201/ helps you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [HK boy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9724138/hk-boy)
The following works, it installs pip explicitly for the python version specified :

```
curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
sudo python get-pip.py
```

I already had `pip3` before hand, so to install packages for python3, `pip3 install <package>` is enough.